# How to format page margins in officer?

Tags: r, officer

I am trying to produce Word documents from R using `officer`. The [documentation (v0.3.5, 06/23/2019)](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/officer/officer.pdf) states that `body_end_section` and `body_default_section` are deprecated and suggests using `body_end_section_continuous`, `body_end_section_landscape`, `body_end_section_portrait`,
`body_end_section_columns`, or `body_end_section_columns_landscape` instead. However, none of these functions accept a `margins` argument.

When I try to force `body_end_section_columns_landscape` to accept a `margins` argument with the code below, I get the error below:

```
my_doc %<>% 
    body_end_section_columns_landscape(
        widths = c(4.75, 4.75),
        space = 0.5, 
        sep = FALSE, 
        w = 8.5, 
        h = 11, 
        margins = c(top = 0.5, bottom = 0.5, left = 0.5, right = 0.5)
    )
Error in body_end_section_columns_landscape(., widths = c(4.75, 4.75),  : 
  unused argument (margins = c(top = 0.5, bottom = 0.5, left = 0.5, right = 0.5))
```

The documentation for `body_end_section_columns_landscape` states that `w` and `h` are "width and height in inches of the section page. This will be ignored if the default section (of the reference_docx file) already has a width and a height." But I can't find any documentation for `reference_docx`.

When I used the deprecated function `body_end_section` I get a warning and somewhat mangled output:

```
my_doc %<>% 
    body_end_section(
        landscape = TRUE,
        margins = c(top = 0.5, bottom = 0.5, left = 0.5, right = 0.5),
        colwidths = c(0.5, 0.5),
        space = 0.05
    )
Warning message:
body_end_section is deprecated. See ?sections for replacement functions.
```

When I say the output is mangled, I mean:

- paper is A4 (instead of letter)
- top, bottom, and left margins are 0.5" (as expected)
- right margin is 1.04" (instead of 0.5")
- columns are 4.81" wide (instead of 4.75")
- column separator is 0.53" (instead of 0.5")

I can't see a way to make sense of the column and margin widths, even calculating for A4 paper instead of letter paper.

I also

**My question is 3 fold:**

1. How do I change the paper size to letter?
2. Which function should I use to format the columns and margins?
3. If I have to use `body_end_section`, can anyone explain the math needed to get the widths I desire?

Thanks!